# How to use a model inside django settings?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I need to use one of my models to define Django settings variables. Meaning, the django variables will be dinamically defined by what's on the database.

When I use a function that uses one of my models:

```
from util.auth_utils import get_app_auth 
auth = get_app_auth()
```

It throws an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

If I try to use this code inside the settings.py:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

Also throws an error:

```
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
```

Besides that, I tryed to move the django.setup() part to after the INSTALLED_APPS, but then it wont load settings correctly.

Any clues?

Comment: You don't: settings are one of the modules that are loaded first, and `django.setup()` requires the settings. How else it is going to query the database, without first loading the settings that determine how to contact to that database.

Comment: So there isnt a way to dinamically set django variables from a model?

Comment: definitely not setting. In case you really need that you will have to manually open a connection to the database, and make the query. Note that settings are loaded when you start the server, so updating records will not change any settings.

Comment: This would result in a hen / egg problem: to create the database you would need the settings, which would need the database to be created already.

Answer (score 0):

There are probably better approaches, but what you could do is lazy evaluation, so that what is defined when settings is imported is the code which is able to access a database object, and the object is only retrieved when that setting is actually referred to by an app. Provided this is after Django has finished setting up the database and the models, all will be fine.

Here's an example I just cooked up

```
class LazyInstance( object):
    def __init__(self, app_label, modelname, lookupfield, lookupvalue):
      self.appname = app_label
      self.modelname = modelname.lower()
      self.lookupfield = lookupfield
      self.lookupvalue = lookupvalue

    @property
    def value(self):
        if hasattr( self, '_value'):
            return self._value

        print( "LazyInstance getting object")
        from django.apps import apps

        Model = apps.get_model(
            app_label=self.appname,
            model_name=self.modelname)

        self._value = Model.objects.get( 
            **{ self.lookupfield: self.lookupvalue })
        return self._value
```

settings.py:

```
from playpen.lazy_instance import  LazyInstance
PLAY_FOO = LazyInstance( 'stock','memdesc', 'pk', 8552)
```

My development server didn't crash. Using `./manage.py shell_plus`,

```
>>> from django.conf import settings
>>> settings.PLAY_FOO.value
LazyInstance getting object
<MemDesc id=8552: stuff... >
>>> settings.PLAY_FOO.value   # note, no second DB access
<MemDesc id=8552: stuff... >
```

I'll leave pulling the fields you want out of the object and copying them to other attributes of PLAY_FOO as an exercise.